# How to publish PHP based website using visual studio?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2015, publish

I am working on an PHP based website using PHP tools in visual studio 2015 on windows 10 system.
I am stuck because I am not able to publish my website on the server (other machine).
I am able to run the website on localhost ut I need it to be published on server so that other people can also look into the website.

Please suggest me the way I can publish the site keeping in my I do not want to use Azure services to do so.

Any solution sooner will be a great help.

Comment: That depends on what kind of access you have to the server. RDC and FTP spring to mind...

Comment: Have FTP at server.

Comment: Does the website have a domain yet?

Answer (score 0):

for your kind information PHP requires Apache server . Try go daddy hosting or google hosting for php website

Comment: Already using Apache server, our website won't even run without Apache.
Any other specific configuration we need to do to publish an php website via VS?